# SonarQube is not accepting the instanbul code coverage lcov.info file

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, istanbul

I am trying to import instanbul code coverage into sonarQube by passing the lcov.info file. Here is how my sonar-project.properties file look like.

Currently sonar is generating it's own code coverage report and displaying the unit test code coverage % instead of displaying the content from lcov.info file that I am passing

Comment: My Sonar-project.properties looks like   # Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=musicservice:consumer-mixpanel
sonar.projectName=Consumer-Mixpanel
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Additional parameters
sonar.my.property=value
sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**/*.*,istanbulReport/**,test/**.statsd/**
sonar.language=js
#sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths=xunit.xml
sonar.doxygen.generateDocumentation=enable
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=istanbulReport/coverage/reports/lcov.info

Comment: "sonar is generating it's own code coverage report and displaying the unit  test code coverage % instead of displaying the content from lcov.info" Do you mean that the % displayed via SonarQube UI is different from what you have with Istanbul ? How different is it ? Is the percentage greater or les than what you are suppose to have ? Could you run an analysis in debug mode and see in the log if there is anything related to the lcov report analysis ?

Comment: @Linda-SonarSourceTeam we have the same issue. Overall Condition Coverage in SonarQube is almost the same as Istanbul's branch coverage but Line Coverage is completely different... almost about 20% difference. Even in settings of Sonar, it is pointing to lcov.info but it seems to be ignored by Sonar.

Comment: @Linda-SonarSourceTeam There is also a difference in our back-end application. So the back-end application is all Java and we are using Cobertura. It's a multi module application, so I wonder how Sonar calculate the overall coverage by getting the result of the two module? Because the percentage doesn't match either module's coverage so I am guessing it somehow calculates the average... is that right?

Comment: Where did you find how to configure jest and coverage.